# How to tell if jedis was added to classpath?

Tags: java, jar, redis, classpath, jedis

How do I know if the jar has been added to the classpath of the java application AccessRedis.java?

I have read many posts about it but did not help. I have ssh'ed into a RHEL 6.8 server and I am trying to add a jedis 2.9.0 jar to the classpath when compiling a java application. This is the application:

```
import redis.*;

public class AccessRedis {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Simple redis instance");

    }
}
```

This is the command I am using to compile the java file:

```
javac -cp ".:/home/username/jedis-2.9.0.jar" AccessRedis.java
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AccessRedis.java:1: error: package redis does not exist
import redis.*;
^
1 error
```

How do I know if the jar has been added to the classpath? Am I adding the jar to the classpath correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no classes with `redis.*` , 
instead `import redis.clients.jedis.*`

Comment: Thanks ravthiru! I was trying to import a directory it seems.